# BOT Framework emulator stopped rendering HTML

Tags: emulation, botframework

Bot Framework suddenly stopped rendering html, I have attached screenshot. What can be wrong? I am using v3.5.31 which is the latest one. I have used Bot Application template which is bydefault available when creating new BOT project.

Below is the code i have written

```
[Serializable]
    public class RootDialog : IDialog<object>
    {
        public Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
        {
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
        {
            PromptDialog.Text(context, resumeAfter, "Enter your name", "Didn't get that",
                      3
                      );
        }

        private async Task resumeAfter(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
        {
            string answer = await result;
            await context.PostAsync($"Hello <i><b>{answer}</b></i>");
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: There is some discussion about html in WebChat (which the emulator includes) here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/604

Comment: Thanks Eric, Is there any mechanism to get notifications about such changes?

Comment: I'm sorry, but there is not currently a mechanism for notifications about changes (other than subscribing to changes in the GitHub repository).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was reported [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/issues/261). and it looks like it's by design in the WebChat control (that is what the Emulator uses behind the scenes). See the change in the WebChat control: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/commit/a5cd8cffb7a97fb925e4078dbe1085694fa92f80